# Data frame has multiple variables but is only showing one - R

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

I've read in a tab delimited file with the headers and the data frame has 4 columns and 325 observations; however, the data frame is showing that there is only one column to call. Like this:

| Var1...Var2...Var3...Var4 |
| --- |
| 12 12 13 14 |
| 11 14 12 9 |

And I can't call a singular column because of this. Say I type:

```
data.set[,1]
```

It does not only call the first column but the entire data frame. How do I fix this?

Comment: It has not been read in correctly (obviously).  Post the code you used to read it in (and a sample of the data). Either it's not tab separated or something else is awry with the command used.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I've edited the post so a ss of the original text file is at the top of the post, and the code i used to read it in is 'read.table(file.choose(), sep = '\t', header = TRUE)'

Comment: The whitespace character can't be discerned from a screenshot so that's not helpful.  Regardless, it seems your data is not tab separated so instead try `read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE)`.